# find values in a column and select the cells in the same row

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working in a code to find the values "SIM" in the column F and select all the cells in the same row in column A and B. It is working, however, there are 2 "SIM", so it should select cells A and B in 2 rows, but it only did in one! can someone help me?
thanks

```
Sub teste()

'Alterar todo mes

Dim TR As Long, i As Long

Worksheets("Format2").Activate

'Alterar todo mes

TR = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = TR To 1 Step -1
    If (Range("F" & i)) = "SIM" Then
    Rows(i).Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Range("A1:b1").Select
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you meant `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Select`

Comment: @findwindow - that's effectively the same thing...

Comment: @TimWilliams I guess I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Tested:

```
Sub teste()

    Dim TR As Long, i As Long, rng As Range
    Dim sht as WorkSheet

    Set sht = Worksheets("Format2")
    sht.Activate
    TR = sht.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = TR To 1 Step -1
        If sht.Range("F" & i).Value = "SIM" Then
            If rng Is Nothing then
                Set rng = sht.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1,2)
            Else
                Set rng = Application.Union(rng, sht.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1,2))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Select
End Sub
```